# RSACryptoServiceProvider encrypt and decrypt using own public and private key

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm told that for asymmetric cryptography you encrypt plaintext with your public key and decrypt it with your private key. So i've tried the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        string pubkey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        string prikey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);

        byte[] someThing = RSAEncrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Hello World"), pubkey);
        byte[] anotherThing = RSADecrypt(someThing, prikey);

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(anotherThing));
    }
```

and the encrypt and decrypt functions

```
    public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] plaintext, string destKey)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(destKey);
        encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(plaintext, true);
        rsa.Dispose();
        return encryptedData;
    }

    public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] ciphertext, string srcKey)
    {
        byte[] decryptedData;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(srcKey);
        decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(ciphertext, true);
        rsa.Dispose();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

I'm expecting the console to display `Hello World`, but it displays this `SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkAA==`. Am i using RSACryptoServiceProvider wrongly?

Comment: You are converting your decrypted string to Base64 encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is base 64, decode the string and you will get "Hello world".

Answer (score 3):

Your last line should read:

```
 Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(anotherThing));
```

Currently you are converting the decrypted string to Base64 encoding